# Are static data members safe as C++ default arguments?

Tags: c++, initialization

Do I need to worry about the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) when using a static data member as a default argument value?  For example:

```
class Thing {

    static double const default_blarg;  // initialized in another file

    void run(double blarg=default_blarg);

};
```

I know `default_blarg` will be initialized at a mostly-unspecified point at link time, but I'm not sure when the default argument to `run` is initialized.  If it's at some point that could be before `default_blarg` is initialized, what approach could I use to safely expose the default value as part of the class interface without repeating it?  Would using `constexpr` for the static data member make it safe?

Note that I'm aware that this could yield some very confusing behavior if `default_blarg` wasn't const (that's why it is), and I'm not trying to use a non-static data member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still have to be worried about the static initialization order fiasco.  Lets say you have a.cpp and b.cpp.  In a.cpp you have

```
double const Thing::default_blarg = 0;
```

Now in a.cpp any call to `run` after this point will have a initialized default and you are good to go.  Unfortunately in b.cpp you have another static object that happens to create an instance of `Thing` and call `run`.

Now we do not know what will happen.  If b.cpp runs first then `default_blarg` is not initialized and we have undefined behavior.

Now for you second part

> but I'm not sure when the default argument to run is initialized

The default arguments of a function are evaluated each time the function is called.  So as long as the function is called after `default_blarg` is initialized(and as noted above it may not) you will be okay.

Answer (score 5):

From the C++11 Standard, Section 8.3.6/9:

> Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called.

As long as `Thing::default_blarg` is initialized before `Thing::run` is called, you should see predictable behavior.