# Default (Optional) Arguments as references c++

Tags: c++, overloading, pass-by-reference, default-arguments

Is it in anyway possible (without using boost) to have a function in c++ as follows :

`void foo(int x, classX &obj = *(new classX()))`

The `classX` is used multiple times in my codebase and there are many such functions which have a similar signature (i.e. use this class object as a default argument). Is it possible to achieve this without an overloaded call?

Comment: If the reference is `const` then you can do: `void foo(int x, const classX &obj = classX())`, otherwise using an overload is cleaner: `void foo(int x){ classX obj; foo(x, obj); } void foo(int x, classX &obj) {...}`

Comment: `void foo(int x, const classX &obj = {});`

Comment: hmm .. should each of these references refer to the same object?

Comment: Why would you want to use operator `new` by default?    That is a very effective way of causing a memory leak, if `foo()` ever forgets/fails to use the corresponding operator `delete`?

Comment: Why not just use normal pointers and dereference them in-function? However, perhaps [reference wrappers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) may help.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson, because “normal pointers” are [evil](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#defn-evil). Well, naked `new` is also evill anyway.

Comment: @JanHudec Oh, I totally agree. That's why smart pointers are better. I never really specified in my comment to use raw pointer lol.

Comment: What does the function do with the argument, and why do you want to avoid overloading? Selecting the right approach depends on those things.

Comment: I agree and understood the folly and did change the design as it was becoming unmanageable and caused other problems. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you provided certainly compiles and "works", but I **strongly** advise against such a thing.

The function returns `void` so that means the either referenced or allocated object (or its presumed owner) does not leave the function. It must thus, if allocated, be destroyed (otherwise, that's someone else's problem, outside that function).

However, that isn't even possible, there is nobody who owns the object, or has a pointer to it! So not only do you have a *possible* memory leak there, you have a *guaranteed* memory leak (in case no object is passed), unless you add yet another ugly hack that derives a pointer from the reference only to destroy the object. That's very unpleasant.

Plus, even if you get this done (in a no-leak way), you have useless object allocation and destruction for every function call. Although one shouldn't optimize prematurely, one *also* shouldn't pessimize prematurely by adding regular allocations and deallocations that are not just unnecessary but actually decrease code quality.

Something that's better would be:

```
//namespace whatever {
classX dummy;
//}
#include <memory>

void foo(int x, classX &obj = dummy)
{
    if(std::addressof(obj) != std::addressof(dummy))
    { /* do something using object */ }
    else
    { /* no object supplied */ }
}
```

Yep, that's a global used for a good cause. You can make the global a singleton if that makes you feel better, or a static class member, all the same. Either way, you have exactly one object, no allocations, no leaks, and you can still pass an object to the function if you wish. And, you can distinguish these two cases.

Comment: That, however, makes the function non-reentrant unless the reference is const.

Comment: @JanHudec: How so? The dummy object or its address hardly changes after being initialized at startup. You will hardly do anything with it but compare whether it's the dummy. It wouldn't make sense to do anything but that. I was, by the way, going to suggest that the reference be `const` (to communicate this), but seeing how in the object-provided case one _may_ actually want to modify the passed object, that probably won't work.

Comment: the only thing that makes sense is to not distinguish whether the argument is dummy or not! If you need to distinguish, the code will in most cases be simpler and cleaner with two overloads. So the obvious assumption is that the argument will be used always, and since it isn't `const`, modified.

Comment: @JanHudec: Thing is, the OP explicitly wants no overload, so that's out of the question. We know too little to tell for sure, but... you can _probably_ even modify the dummy object concurrently since the fact that you corrupt it doing so is _probably_ inconsequential. Yes, you can construct an example where this is not the case (I'm aware). Hence, lacking the possibility of an overload, I prefer to distinguish the cases "object provided" and "object not provided". It's not clear whether I can meaninfully modify a default-constructed object either (without doing something extra first).

Comment: If it is just an optional return-by-reference, it wouldn't matter. But if the object has some useful methods that are called in the process, it probably does.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question (or comments) that says it is. Thus, that would be speculation. We don't know. It may as well be anything else. Could be a logger instance, could be a callback function object, could be a list of values to apply as filter, could be a `BasicLockable` for optional thread-safety. It could be anything optional.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that says it isn't, therefore an answer shall assume the worse.

Answer (score 0):

To use a global shared instance as default argument is possible.

With

```cpp
extern inline classX globalClassX;
void foo(int x, classX &obj = globalClassX);
```

it should be accomplished.

However, I'm quite uncertain about the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) which may interfere.

This can be solved using Meyers Singleton approach instead:

```cpp
classX& getGlobalClassX()
{
  static ClassX classX;
  return classX;
}

void foo(int x, classX &obj = getGlobalClassX);
```

An MCVE for demonstration:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct Object {
  inline static unsigned idGen = 1;
  unsigned id;
  const std::string name;
  explicit Object(const std::string &name = std::string()): id(idGen++), name(name) { }
};

Object& getGlobalObj()
{
  static Object objGlobal("global");
  return objGlobal;
}

void doSomething(int x, Object &obj = getGlobalObj());

#define PRINT_AND_DO(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  PRINT_AND_DO(doSomething(0));
  PRINT_AND_DO(Object obj("local"));
  PRINT_AND_DO(doSomething(1, obj));
  PRINT_AND_DO(doSomething(2));
}

void doSomething(int x, Object &obj)
{
  std::cout << "doSomething(x: " << x << ", obj: Object("
    << obj.id << ", '" << obj.name << "'))\n";
}
```

Output:

```
doSomething(0);
doSomething(x: 0, obj: Object(1, 'global'))
Object obj("local");
doSomething(1, obj);
doSomething(x: 1, obj: Object(2, 'local'))
doSomething(2);
doSomething(x: 2, obj: Object(1, 'global'))
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1fb235607dc9363)

---

Another Q/A I consulted while writing:

[SO: Are static data members safe as C++ default arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39397028/7478597)